# useSound hook with array of sounds

Tags: reactjs, usesound

I want to use [this useSound hook](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/announcing-use-sound-react-hook/) with an array of sounds. I am able to play the sounds as described in a typical example in the [docs](https://github.com/joshwcomeau/use-sound), and also a single sound played within a separate function (which I may be doing incorrectly). But what I ultimately want to do is to play a sound from an array from a separate function. Below is my code showing something close to what I want to accomplish (part 3) if it were working. Here is a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-christian-lnl18s?file=/src/App.js:0-1254). How would I correctly play the sound from an array?

```
import "./styles.css";
import sound0 from "./audio/sound0.mp3";
import sound1 from "./audio/sound1.mp3";
import sound2 from "./audio/sound2.mp3";
import useSound from "use-sound";

export default function App() {
  // 1. Sound declarations according to typical example (working)
  const [soundEffect0] = useSound(sound0);
  const [soundEffect1] = useSound(sound1);
  const [soundEffect2] = useSound(sound2);

  // 2. Function plays sound (working)
  function playSound() {
    soundEffect0();
  }

  // 3. Desired Method playing sound from array of sounds (not working)
  const [soundEffects] = useSound([sound0, sound1, sound2]);

  function playSoundFromArray(idx) {
    soundEffects[idx]();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>1. Example Method (working)</h2>
      <button onClick={soundEffect0}>soundEffect0</button>
      <button onClick={soundEffect1}>soundEffect1</button>
      <button onClick={soundEffect2}>soundEffect2</button>

      <h2>2. Playing sound within function (working)</h2>
      <button onClick={playSound}>playSound function</button>

      {/* <h2>3. Desired Method playing sound from array of sounds (not working)</h2>
      <button onClick={playSoundFromArray(0)}>soundEffect0</button> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the 3rd party hook, but one approach could simply be to call the hook as you currently do but "re-shape" the data into an array between the use of hooks and binding it in the JSX: `const soundEffects = [soundEffect0, soundEffect1, soundEffect2];`  It's still the same references to the same functions/objects/etc, just wrapped in an array.

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid that you are miss understanding how multiple source are supposed to work. You may have a look to [this merged](https://github.com/joshwcomeau/use-sound/pull/52#issue-752770977) PR.

Looks like you cannot play a sound by index (which is what you are trying to do). This is how it works:

```js
const Player = () => {
  const [play] = useSound([soundfile1, soundfile2]);

  return <div onClick={() => play()}>Play</div>;
};
```